# Laravel : Join other table column into one row using alias

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, postgresql

I want to take shift schedule of multiple people for one month and put that shift into one row with those people data.

this is my table.

`karyawans table`

[image]

`schedules table`

[image]

the best i can do is using `with` and iterate it with for loops then manually build my object like this

```
$thisMonth = Carbon::create(request()->year, request()->month);
        $firstday = $thisMonth->copy()->firstOfMonth();
        $lastday = $thisMonth->copy()->lastOfMonth();

$schedules = Karyawan::with(['schedules' => function ($query) use ($firstday, $lastday) {
            $query->whereBetween('tgl', [$firstday, $lastday]);
        }])
            ->where('id_ruang', $karyawan->id_ruang)
            ->orderBy('nik', 'asc')->get();

foreach ($schedules as $s) {
            $obj = new stdClass();
            $obj->nik = $s->nik;
            $obj->nama = $s->nama;

            for ($i = 0; $i < $last; $i++) {
                $obj->{'day' . ($i + 1)} = empty($s->schedules[$i]) ? null : $s->schedules[$i]->id_shift;
            }

            array_push($data, $obj);
        }
```

this is the output

```
{
    "nik": 1659,
    "nama": "Muhammad Nando Hidayat",
    "day1": 1,
    "day2": 1,
    "day3": 1,
    "day4": 1,
    "day5": 1,
    "day6": 1,
    "day7": 1,
    "day8": 1,
    "day9": 1,
    "day10": 1,
    "day11": 1,
    "day12": 1,
    "day13": 1,
    "day14": 1,
    "day15": 1,
    "day16": 1,
    "day17": 1,
    "day18": 1,
    "day19": 1,
    "day20": 1,
    "day21": 1,
    "day22": 1,
    "day23": 1,
    "day24": 1,
    "day25": 1,
    "day26": 1,
    "day27": 1,
    "day28": 1,
    "day29": 1,
    "day30": 1,
    "day31": 1,
  },
```

that's the output that i want.
but is there any laravel query way to achieve the same thing without using for loop?
just laravel query

Comment: What you have done is also laravel query

Comment: @YasinPatel what i demand is the output without for looping. sorry for the misconception.

Comment: What's your output of $schedules? @nandohidayat